# windows location href to div(id)

Tags: javascript

How to make window.location go to the same page but with another different div tag. (example: href="#div1").

```js
function gotoDiv(){
    var gotoDivID=Math.round(Math.random()*2)
    var links=new Array()
    links[0]="#div1"
    links[1]="#div2"
    links[2]="#div3"
         window.location=links[gotoDivID]    }
```

```html
<form><input type="button" value="go to div" onClick="gotoDiv()"></form>
</br></br>
 
<div id="div1" style="width:40px; height:45px; background:blue; color:#fff;">Div1</div>
<div id="div2" style="width:40px; height:45px; background:purple; color:#fff">Div2</div>
<div id="div3" style="width:40px; height:45px; background:orange; color:#fff;">Div3</div>
```

Comment: Easier array construction btw: `var links = ["#div1", "#div2", "#div3"];`

Comment: I think this statement `  window.location=links[gotoDivID]`  should be `  window.location.hash=links[gotoDivID]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function gotoDiv() {
  var links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div[id]")).map(ele => ("#" + ele.innerHTML.toLowerCase())); //get an array of div's innerHTML prefixed with #
  //console.log( links );
  var gotoDivID = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length); //get a random value between 0 and number of divs
  //console.log(gotoDivID);
  location.hash = links[gotoDivID];
}
```

**Demo**

```js
function gotoDiv() {
  var links = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("div[id]")).map(ele => ("#" + ele.innerHTML.toLowerCase())); //get an array of div's innerHTML prefixed with #
  //console.log( links );
  var gotoDivID = Math.floor(Math.random() * links.length); //get a random value between 0 and number of divs
  //console.log(gotoDivID);
  location.hash = links[gotoDivID];
}
```

```css
div {
  margin-top: 400px;
}
```

```html
<form><input type="button" value="go to div" onClick="gotoDiv()"></form>
</br>
</br>

<div id="div1" style="width:40px; height:45px; background:blue; color:#fff;">Div1</div>
<div id="div2" style="width:40px; height:45px; background:purple; color:#fff">Div2</div>
<div id="div3" style="width:40px; height:45px; background:orange; color:#fff;">Div3</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much,  been spent 30 minutes figuring it out on my own

Answer (score 0):

Applying Math.round is not what you want. Math.random() returns 0<=x<1, so just multiply with the count of your divs and truncate to int.

You can set the hash directly using `window.location.hash`.

```js
function gotoDiv(){
  var divs =  ["div1", "div2", "div3"];
  var hash = divs[parseInt(Math.random()*divs.length)];
  window.location.hash = hash;
  // output to see something here 
  console.info(hash)
}
gotoDiv();
```

```html
<form><input type="button" value="go to div" onClick="gotoDiv()"></form>
</br></br>
 
<div id="div1" style="width:40px; height:45px; background:blue; color:#fff;">Div1</div>
<div id="div2" style="width:40px; height:45px; background:purple; color:#fff">Div2</div>
<div id="div3" style="width:40px; height:45px; background:orange; color:#fff;">Div3</div>
```